# Windows UAC Security With Exe

Tags: windows, uac, privileges, signing

I have an exe created with an old Borland C++ compiler.  It needs administrator privileges to function correctly.  Since the app will run at startup, I do not want the user prompted if it's OK to run the program (testing on Win7).  My question is is there ANY way to remove that annoying prompt every time the app is run?

I added a manifest file with admin privs and signed it, but it then still appears with the publisher name.

This will be distributed, so I don't want users to have to turn off UAC or do anything too complicated.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

I am hoping there's something for UAC like "Always Trust This Program" or something.

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose of UAC.

Comment: No, I was hoping there was something for UAC like "Always Trust This Program" or something.  Please remove your -1.

Comment: It's not my -1 but I'll throw a +1 up there to even it out

Comment: I found this way, but it's too difficult unless I can reproduce programatically:   
http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-create-program-shortcut-run-without-uac-prompt-windows-7.htm

Comment: I found my answer here and just have to try it now.
[http://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7](http://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

Comment: You should ask yourself how your program will behave if UAC is disabled. The user **is** a standard user; with no UAC convenience feature. Will your app crash horribly on startup? What did you do on Windows XP? Did the program simply crash horribly there too? These are not idle questions. You need to think about standard user and handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be using a scheduled task to run at logon. Scheduled tasks are launched by the task scheduler service which runs with SYSTEM privileges, and therefore it's possible to have them run with elevated privileges without prompting the user on startup. You still have to get the user's confirmation once - when you set up the scheduled task - but not every time the program runs.

Since I don't know how you are installing your program (which installer you are using, if any), I'll describe to you a way which you can probably implement in any environment: Using `schtasks.exe` and an XML file. (Note that this won't work with Windows XP and older, but there you don't have to worry about UAC anyway.)

You need to create an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2013-11-01T00:00:00.0000000</Date>
        <Author>USERDOMAIN\USERNAME</Author>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <LogonTrigger>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <UserId>USERDOMAIN\USERNAME</UserId>
        </LogonTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
            <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
            <UserId>USERDOMAIN\USERNAME</UserId>
            <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
        <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
        <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
        <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
        <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
        <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
        <IdleSettings>
            <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
            <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
        </IdleSettings>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Hidden>false</Hidden>
        <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
        <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
        <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
        <Priority>7</Priority>
    </Settings>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>c:\path\to\your\app.exe</Command>
            <Arguments>/your /parameters</Arguments>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

- Replace all `USERDOMAIN\USERNAME` here with the actual user's domain and name. You can, for example, read those out of the corresponding environment variables `USERDOMAIN` and `USERNAME`.
- Replace `c:\path\to\your\app.exe` with your application's path and `/your /parameters` with the arguments you want to pass to your app, if any.
- The secret magic here lies in `<RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>` which will make the task scheduler run your app elevated.
- The `Date` doesn't really matter, but for completeness you could set it to the current date and time.

After creating the XML file and saving it somewhere (e.g. temporary folder), you have to run this command which will create the actual task: `schtasks.exe /Create /TN "My App" /F /XML "c:\path\to\xmlfile.xml"` (replace `My App` with the name which should appear in the task scheduler when viewed).

You can delete the task again using `schtasks.exe /Delete /TN "My App"`.

(For a pure C++ solution, you could also take [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381911(v=vs.85).aspx) and add the missing things which would be specifying the username and setting the flag for using the highest available privileges.)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this because although CherryDT's answer is a good approach, longer-run depending on context it may be a little inflexible.

Another option (depending on the context) may be to refactor into two components:

1. A system service which runs at startup and does everything that needs admin access
2. A client program that communicates with the service and does not need admin access.

This avoids the annoying prompt but it is more work.  Based on your description it is not clear this is the right way to go here, but it may be down the road (and for others finding this ticket) so I figure it is worth mentioning separately.